# How do I pipe a downloaded file to standard output in bash?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, wget, pipe

How is it possible to pipe out `wget`'s downloaded file? If not what alternatives should I use?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
wget -O - -o /dev/null  http://google.com
```

Comment: The -o /dev/null is only necessary if you truly don't care about errors, since without that errors will be written to stderr (while the file is written to stdout).

Comment: right. or you can check error codes... as long as you pipe output to a file not another command.

Comment: AFAIK, no need to -o /dev/null because that goes to stderr anyway.

Comment: You can use `wget -qO- $URL` to simplify things.

Comment: `wget -qO- $URL` works if you're using Wget on Windows

Answer (score 38):

Or use curl, where it's the default behaviour.

```
curl http://www.google.com/
```

http://curl.haxx.se/

Comment: `-s` won't hurt to make it quiet, particularly with a small file.

Answer (score 6):

There are other methods you can use instead of wget and curl:

You can use lynx:

```
# lynx -source http://www.google.com
```

w3m:

```
# w3m -dump_source http://www.google.com
```

and libwww-perl comes with a handy program called GET (as well has HEAD and POST, which do what you think they do)

```
# GET http://www.google.com
```

Comment: Offtopic, but I've used lynx in some of my scripts to parse html for me automatically whenever I've needed the content of a page and didn't care about the markup. It's great for that

Comment: indeed, both lynx and w3m have a -dump option. I prefer w3m for its table and frame support.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

```
URL='http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/akismet/'
curl -s "$URL" | egrep -o "http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/[^']+" | xargs wget -qO-
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another option:  I often use  lwp-request, from libwww-perl, for this.   It outputs to STDOUT by default and is more likely than curl to be installed on the systems I use (your situation my vary).

Comment: FWIW, Mac OS has curl (not wget) and I believe other BSD's do as well. As do a lot of embedded *nix systems I've used. Not sure if Perl is more common than curl.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [Aria2](https://aria2.github.io). It's powerful downloader.

```
aria2c http://google.com.tw
```

Comment: Does it output to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) (the crux of the question)?