# Unzip from stdin to stdout - funzip, python

Tags: linux, bash, python, compression, pipe

The goal is to read a zip file from stdin and uncompress to stdout.

Funzip works and is the solution I am looking for, the zip contains a single file, unfortunately funzip fails when the compressed file size is around 1GB or greater:

```
funzip error: invalid compressed data--length error
```

Update: I have discovered the above error may not indicate an actual error. Comparing two uncompressed files, one unzipped traditionally and the other through a pipe using funzip (with the above error written to stderr) the files are identical. I'd like to keep this open, so this can be confirmed or reported.

A related solution using python:
[Unzipping files that are flying in through a pipe](https://serverfault.com/questions/26474/unzipping-files-that-are-flying-in-through-a-pipe/)

However this output is directed to a file.

Answer (score 14):

Repost of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52759718/9645167):

BusyBox's `unzip` can take stdin and extract all the files to stdout. For example, when you use `wget` as stdin,

```
wget -qO- http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.2.5.3.zip | busybox unzip -p -
```

`-p` to extract files to pipe. The dash after is to use stdin as input.

You also can, (just like [previous](https://serverfault.com/a/735915/491554) answer)

```
cat file.zip | busybox unzip -p -
```

But that's just redundant of `unzip -p file.zip`.

If your distro uses BusyBox by default (e.g. Alpine), just run `unzip -p -`.

Answer (score 8):

Use `bsdtar` from [`libarchive`](https://libarchive.org/):

```
> curl 'https://example.com/some.zip' | bsdtar -xOf - | less
```

Comment: For Cygwin, bsdtar has its own package `bsdtar`.

Comment: bsdtar drops permissions when reading the archive from stdin.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `zcat`. For example:

`cat file.zip | zcat`

Please note that in the example above the first part (`cat file.zip`) is redundant, in the sense that you can simply issue `zcat file.zip` and have the same results. I included it only to show that `zcat` is capable to read from `stdin`

Comment: Wrong asnwer: zcat doesn't work with zip files! This answer should be downvoted. A solution can be found here using jar though: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2690/how-to-redirect-output-of-wget-as-input-to-unzip

Comment: @Eric on my CentOS 6 box, I surely can use `zcat file.zip` to show zipped files. For example: `file services.zip` returns `services.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract`, and I can `zcat service.zip` to show its content

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work on CentOS 6.9 when using a zip file that contains more than one file. I get `gzip: zip file has more than one entry--rest ignored` which is totally understandable since piping creates a stream and a stream is not seekable so `zcat` can't jump to the end of file to retrieve the files list. So in a nutshell `zcat` (actually `gunzip` since `zcat` calls it) doesn't work with zip files except when they contain only one file. Try it, you'lls see.

Comment: I was under the impression that OP really want to output to `stdout` a single zipped file, not an entire zip archive. After all, what is the point of showing multiple, concatenated files on `stdout`, when you can not tell were is start/end of each file?

Comment: @shodanshok, the point is you can add a filename from the list as cmd line argument to unzipper so that the output contains only that file. Yet as Eric pointed out that doesn't work with unzip if the input is a stream.

Comment: The OP's question literally says "the zip contains a single file". That matches my own use case, and this answer is by far the simplest solution for me. Absolutely deserves upvotes, not down.

Comment: This only works for some versions of `gzip`, and for these you can also just pipe directly to `gunzip`!

Answer (score 1):

regarding stdout: unzip supports that out of the box with its -c and -p options.
regarding stdin: Eric pointed out that the zip format has its directory at the end of the file, so the only way to make it streamable is to copy the input to a temporary storage. The following simple script does that:

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage: unzipOnTheFly [unzipArgs]
# unzipArgs: additional args to be passed to unzip
tmpFile=/tmp/unzipOnTheFly.$$.zip
cat >$tmpFile
unzip -p $tmpFile "$@"
rm $tmpFile
```

In the above case the solution would be

```
<file.zip unzipOnTheFly
```

If the archive contains more than one file and you want only one you can say

```
<file.zip unzipOnTheFly pathToOneFile
```

Answer (score -1):

Uncompressing (with redirect to `file`):

```
cat file.gz | gunzip -c - > file
```

Compressing (with redirect to `file.gz`)):

```
cat file | gzip -c - > file.gz
```

Comment: zip ang gzip are not the same thing. zip files stores the list of files at the end of the stream which makes it impractical for piping in while downloading. gzip doesn't have that limitation. This answer should be downvoted.

Comment: This guy... zcat and gunzip do handle zip files, as long as the zip file only contains a single file, which is the case for this question. This answer is not the simplest but does answer the question and does not deserve downvotes.

Comment: Only some versions of gzip support ZIP files, so this at least needs to contain a clarification of what gzip versions this works with (or even better, on which OSes these are commonly found).